# Grab last 8 quarters start and end dates between two dates

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to grab start and end dates of every quarter between two dates

```
declare @pdtmParameter1 datetime = '30-Jun-2015'
declare @pdtmParameter2 datetime = '31-Mar-2017'

SELECT DISTINCT


Result should be

2015-03-31 00:00:00.000 2015-06-30 00:00:00.000
2015-07-01 00:00:00.000 2015-09-30 00:00:00.000
2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 2015-12-30 00:00:00.000
2015-12-31 00:00:00.000 2016-03-30 00:00:00.000
2016-03-31 00:00:00.000 2016-06-30 00:00:00.000
2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 2016-09-30 00:00:00.000
2016-10-01 00:00:00.000 2016-12-30 00:00:00.000
2016-12-31 00:00:00.000 2017-03-30 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Unless you have a numbers table or calendar table, then the basic method is to list them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @pdtmParameter1 datetime = '30-Jun-2015'
declare @pdtmParameter2 datetime = '31-Mar-2017'

        SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(Day,1,DATEADD(Month, (number-1)*3-3, @pdtmParameter1) ) AS QuarterStart,
        DATEADD(Month, (number-1)*3, @pdtmParameter1)   AS QuarterEnd
    FROM    (SELECT number
FROM (
  VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), 
         (6), (7), (8)
) [1 to 8](number)


    WHERE   number BETWEEN 1 AND 8 ) getnumbers
```

Comment: I don't recognise this as MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Exact Quarter Start and End dates:

```
declare @pdtmParameter1 datetime = '30-Jun-2015'
declare @pdtmParameter2 datetime = '31-Mar-2017'

DECLARE @QUARTER_START INT
SET @QUARTER_START = DATEDIFF(q, 0, @pdtmParameter1)

SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT DATEADD(QUARTER, @QUARTER_START+QTR, 0) AS StartOfQuarter
    ,DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(QUARTER, @QUARTER_START+QTR+1, 0)) AS EndOfQuarter
    FROM (
        SELECT QTR
        FROM (
            VALUES (0),(1), (2), (3), (4),(5), (6), (7), (8)
            ) [NUMBERS](QTR)
         )T 
    )RESULT WHERE EndOfQuarter >= @pdtmParameter1 and EndOfQuarter <= @pdtmParameter2
```